# Editing (by user) Many-to-Many in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Backgound:** I'm updating a relatively simple incident-tracking database for the deputies handling security at a courthouse. There are several many-to-many relationships (incident could include several deputies, several 10-code classificiations, several locations), so multiple intermediate tables to join the various tables. I'm using multi-select list boxes on the input form, then writing those via code to the appropriate tables (I didn't see an easier way to do that). That's all reasonably simple. Now I need to set up a form for users to be able to edit an incident after the fact.

**The Problem:** What I'm picturing seems more complicated than I'd expected. I'm planning to replicate the same UI they get when creating a new incident record, so a form with multiple multi-select list boxes. I'll have to use VBA to find the related entries in the appropriate tables and set the appropriate items to "selected" status. Then, when they click to save changes, I'll have to examine each list item, compare its status (selected or not) to the status in the existing table entries (exists or not) and make changes if appropriate.

Is there an easier way to get to this? It feels like I'm missing something that would make this easier to do.

I could post the db if that will help, though it's in pretty preliminary stages.

Comment: _Is there an easier way to get to this?_ Well, not really. Your approach seems sensible. An alternative would be a subform bound to the junction table where you can select items to add using a combobox that displays the related field (you can do that with very little code), but the UI is very different for that so you'll have to decide which you think is most user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, consider refraining from multi-select listboxes and even multi-value fields which hinder the normalized, relational model. Also, keep intricate code to a minimum when using MS Access especially in initial stages of development. Most simple use cases can run user interface and reporting with hardly any module VBA code.

Specifically, rather than a single *Incidents* table with multiple foreign keys to lookup tables, add related separate **one-to-many** tables for *IncidentsDeputies*, *IncidentsLocations*, and *IncidentsClassifications*. Then on the intake form of *Incidents*, integrate subforms of each as shown below with random data. Use datasheets for quick entries with filter/search/sort functionality like spreadsheets and supports comboboxes if setup in table design (as [lookup fied](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239)) or form design. Advise users to add as many deputies, locations, and classifications per each incident at the bottom. For reporting you would similarly integrate subreports.

[image: Form Example]

If needed, you can set up a reverse interface where you integrate an *Incidents* subform in each of the forms for three child tables for quick lookup and navigation of all corresponding incidents.

One challenge with this approach is querying as an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` across all tables will bring in many pairwise matches. For this reason, be careful in aggregations (e.g., count, mean, sum) as you will be doubling or tripling or quadrupling or other multiple factors of actual calculated values. However, with this approach querying can be easier as you can run calculations singly on *Incidents* without its child relations present and likewise singly for each child relation with their foreign key, `IncidentID`.

Comment: This is the table structure I'm using, but the user interface of using subforms doesn't seem to allow what they need (just click on an officer to select them). That's why I'm using unbound listboxes (with each list based on a query), then using code to create the appropriate entries.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean *doesn't seem to allow what they need*. Sounds more like they are used to a certain UI setup. Since you are designer, instruct them to enter *all* officers, *all* locations, *all* classifications in corresponding sections per incident. And once again, set up combo boxes for easier entry. Even switch datasheet to continuous subforms and use single select list boxes if they like that.

Comment: Combo boxes don't allow for multiple selections the way listboxes do, and there's no need to be able to type. This needs to be simple for entry - it will sometimes be used in situations where the focus is on action, not data entry. So in this case, best UI is the simplest for the user. Editing will be a rare occurrence, so I'm working to mirror the UI of the initial input screen. I think I've gotten the code worked out for this. I'm loading the edit form from the existing records, writing the original record to an archive, then over-writing with the new selections.